# How to test local network connectivity using mac os terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, mac, terminal, bash-scripting

I am searching for a terminal command or utility to continuously test my local lan connection.
I want to test the connection between my macbook pro and the router.
I am using a powerline and sometimes it disconnects.
I want to test and log these disconnects.
Thank you.

Comment: `ping` is the obvious answer. Do a continuous ping to the router IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ping` returns  rc=1 if it doesn't receive an answer for all packets it sent, so something like:

```
while true
do
    sleep 1
    ping -q -c 1 -w 1 router_address > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo $(date) No connection >> logfile
done
```

...will log in `logfile` the times where `router_address` wasn't reachable.

Comment: Is there an error in the script?It fills the logfile with no connection text although my router (192.168.1.1) is reachable.

Comment: I think w parameter should be replaced with W.

Comment: Try  `ping -q -c 1 -w 1 router_address; echo $?`, it should say `0` if there is a connection, `1` if not. Of course, it assumes that you replace `router_address` by the real router address (or the name of your router if you added it in /etc/hosts or whatever equivalent on your system).

Answer (score 0):

just put this command in terminal :

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

and let it works after a while you can scroll up to see any have any timeout or not !,

you can also put your ping data in file by this command :

```
ping 192.168.1.1 | tee ~/Desktop/ping-results.txt
```